# Running firebase database reference object inside a loop. How can I exit the loop if datasnapshot found. Below is my code

Tags: java, android, firebase

This is my code. I need to exit from for loop while data snapshot exists or not. I have tried with a listener interface that will invoke a call back when a data snapshot found or not. However, this listener is invoking only after all iterations. I need to exit the loop immediately. I even tried saving a boolean value in a shared preference and retrieve that value and check if it is true then only run for loop. But that approach is also not working. What is happening here, for loop is iterating through all users then only I'm getting the result from  firebase background task.

```
private void createBranchAndAddUser(final String userKey) {

    // Getting the referring user from DB
    reference.child("User").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(referredBy)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dst : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            referrerKey = dst.getKey(); // Got referring user firebase key

                            // Getting referring user branches.
                            reference.child("User").child(referrerKey).child("Branch")
                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                                // Branch found under referrer.
                                                if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 1) {
                                                    // One branch found under referrer. Adding one more under referrer.
                                                    Branch branch = new Branch();
                                                    branch.setUser_key(userKey);
                                                    reference.child("User").child(referrerKey).child("Branch").push().setValue(branch);
                                                } else { // Two branch found under referring user. So moving to the next step.

                                                    // GETTING COMPLETE LIST OF USERS WHO ARE REFERRED BY REFERRING USER. (2: Step -> 2)
                                                    reference.child("User").orderByChild("referredBy").equalTo(referredBy).
                                                            addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                                                                        // THIS IS THE LOOP I WANT ESCAPE.
                                                                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                                            User user = ds.getValue(User.class); // Got all users under referrer.
                                                                            final String childUserKey = ds.getKey(); // Got firebase key of first child user under referrer.

                                                                            Log.e(TAG, "isBranch Created " + isBranchCreated);
                                                                            assert childUserKey != null;
                                                                            reference.child("User").child(childUserKey).child("Branch")// getting branches of child user. (2: Step -> 3)
                                                                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                                                        @Override
                                                                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                                                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                                                                                if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 1) {
                                                                                                    // One branch found under child user.
                                                                                                    Branch branch = new Branch();
                                                                                                    branch.setUser_key(userKey);
                                                                                                    reference.child("User").child(childUserKey).child("Branch").push().setValue(branch);

                                                                                                    // need break the loop here, escape from the loop
                                                                                                    isBranchCreated = "YES";
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            } else {
                                                                                                Branch branch = new Branch();
                                                                                                branch.setUser_key(userKey);
                                                                                                reference.child("User").child(childUserKey).child("Branch").push().setValue(branch);

                                                                                                // or break the loop here and escape from the loop.
                                                                                                isBranchCreated = "YES";

                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }

                                                                                        @Override
                                                                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                                                            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    });
                                                                        }
                                                                    }

                                                                }

                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                                    Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                                                                }
                                                            });

                                                }

                                            } else {
                                                // No branch found under referrer.
                                                Branch branch = new Branch();
                                                branch.setUser_key(userKey);
                                                reference.child("User").child(referrerKey).child("Branch").push().setValue(branch);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Indent your code for readable.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you

Comment: Edit the question and use the code formatting tools in the toolbar so the code is readable.